# SQL paramaterization WHERE IN not working

Tags: c#, sql, oledb

I have a specific question about the `WHERE IN` command inside of a parameterized sql query.

**Current situation**
All the normal queries are working, but on the following query example it goes wrong:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table WHERE Id IN(@Ids)
```

**What does this query do?**
This query is selecting all items in the table with the specific ids.

**The error**

```cs
# this generates the following string: "1,2,3,4", which gets parsed into the @Ids param
new OleDbParameter("Ids", String.Join(",", objects.Select(c => c.Id.ToString())));
```

This will generate the folling raw sql query:

```sql
# this is the converted sql query after performing the OleDbCommand.ExecuteNonQueryAsync()
# which is not working
SELECT * FROM table WHERE Id IN("1,2,3,4")
# this is the sql query that is working
SELECT * FROM table where Id IN("1", "2", "3", "4")
```

**solution**
as you can see, the first example is an array, but is not an array inside of the IN statement. How can I change my code so it will get the working sql query with parameterization?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this

```
var ids = new char[objects.Count()];
Array.ForEach(ids, x => x = '?');

var idsList = string.Join(',', ids);

var queryString = $"SELECT * FROM table WHERE Id IN ({idsList})"; 

var command = new OleDbCommand(queryString, connection); 

for (int i = 0; i < ids.Length; i++)
{
    command.Parameters.Add($"@p{i + 1}", OleDbType.VarChar, 5).Value = objects.ElementAt(i).Id; 
} 
  
OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
```